# How do we create a query in MS Access that gives us the cumulative difference?

Tags: sql

I tried using this query: Running Total: CDbl(DSum("[Cost_Replacement]","Cost of Replacement","[RR_Pipe_ID]<=" & [RR_Pipe_ID] & "")) This above query provides the sum not the difference.
My target is to calculate the cumulative difference of the Cost_Replacement column.[image]